# Ubuntu logs out after seconds + no sound + bad keyboard mapping

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, alsa

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I encounter some strange behavior since few weeks, for non-identified reasons.

It could be because I have updated the OS or because I have installed ZOOM (zooom.us) as things stopped working properly since I did so, or because I used Mumble which was the last thing I used before these strange events started to show up.

I use i3 wm for my main session, and I sporadically use the Ubuntu graphical session to test stuff, and here are the things that stopped working from one day to another, altogether:

1. I receive this message every time I start a terminal on my i3 session:

   zsh: locking failed for /home/ostl/.zsh_history: permission denied: reading anyway
2. My keyboard has remapped the Alt and Windows button so I have to remap them everytime I start the i3 session using the following commands:

   xmodmap -e "clear mod1"
   xmodmap -e "clear mod4"
   xmodmap -e "add Mod1 = Super_L"
   xmodmap -e "add Mod4 = Alt_L"

I have added these commands to the i3 config file to remap at the start, and it seems to work only when I directly start on my i3 session, but not through lightdm.

3. The sound does not work at all on the two main sessions (i3 + Graphical session) but works perfectly on the guest session.

I have tried most of the solutions cited here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

4. The Graphical Ubuntu session logs me out of the session after few seconds ~60 seconds.
   I think all of these are correlated since I sense that either some ownership setting have been tweaked unintentionally, or something has occurred on a deeper level and messed up with all of these things.

I would be glad to know if I should pursue individual debugging, or find a way to fix all of these through recovery or similar approach.

I can proceed to diagnostics and paste them here if required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in which my System used to get Logged off after a certain time Then I came to know that it was because my .Xorg file got corrupted.
This is the answer that helped me recover: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22014

I solved the problem by doing this:

> At the login screen Open tty6 terminal using CTRL+ALT+F6 then login using the userid and password

and then reconfigured .Xorg file after stopping the gdm abd then again starting it by using the following command

> **sudo service gdm stop | sudo Xorg -configure | sudo service gdm start**

Then login into the system and it works properly for me.

Hope this helps